# How to have exclusive toggle in unity?

Tags: c#, toggle, unity-game-engine

I can't find a solution that fit my needs, so here's my problem.

I've download an Asset that gives my lots of **Ready Made Component**, I use **8 Toggles**, but they have to be exclusive, here's chat I have in my editor :

[image]

First I was thinking to **attach a script to each toggle**, and use a function that *turn off every button when the trigger onAction is lauchend on a toggle, then turn on only the toggle that launch the trigger*. But it won't work because turning off a button launch is onAction trigger too, and so I go in an *infinite loop*.

Is there a better working way to do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for a toggle group? Like ony one toggle can be select at a time?

Comment: I add all my toggle in a toggle gorup and i can still select them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ToogleGroup to only 1 can be switched on at a time.
Check the documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ToggleGroup.html)

Comment: That was it, but you need to go in the parameter of your toggle and set your group, add it with a drag and drop is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that contains all the toggles (GameObject.Find(name)) as members and when you get onAction call on a toggle script just tell the class which toggle got pressed.. Then in the class you update the gui and control all the toggles

Comment: You can create a public function that receives a string and when the toggle is clicked call the function and pass the current toggle's name or tag as parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Topic : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ToggleGroup Topiz;
      Toggle maybe1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        maybe1 = Topiz.ActiveToggles().FirstOrDefault();

    }

}
```